# How to select columns from a Dataset using Seq<String> in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a Seq and need to use it to select columns in Java

I know about the function `.select(String col, Seq<String> cols)` but I don't have the first column name.

Comment: `df.columns` returns an array with the names of the columns.

Comment: @philantrovert that does it, but why wouldn't they just keep a `.select(Seq<String> cols)` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select using a `Seq<String>` you can split the `Seq` extracting the first element separately:

```java
Seq<String> columns = /* ... */;

Dataframe<Row> newDf = df.select(
    columns.apply(0), // first element
    columns.slice(1, columns.size()) // from the second to the end
);
```

maybe check the length of `columns` first, to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: `select` function takes in input (String,Seq<String>) but slice returns Scala iterable, so had to do toSeq() to it. `columns.slice(...).toSeq()`